# Can we replace an element in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Suppose that I am using Json Path extractor in Jmeter to extract something from the response. But now, I want to use Json extractor.
Is there any easy mechanism from which I can replace all Json Path extractor with Json extractor?

Comment: any feedback on answer ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following Manual Steps to convert JSON Path Extractor to JSON Extractor. Make sure the replacements being done are unique and does not match any variable names or description.

`perl -p -i -e 's/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.JSONPathExtractor/JSONPostProcessor/g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.jsonutils.jsonpathextractor.gui.JSONPathExtractorGui/JSONPostProcessorGui/g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/"VAR"/"JSONPostProcessor.referenceNames"/g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/"DEFAULT"/"JSONPostProcessor.defaultValues"/g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/"JSONPATH"/"JSONPostProcessor.jsonPathExprs"/g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/"VARIABLE"\>\</"JSONPostProcessor.match_numbers"\>1\</g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/.*"SUBJECT".*\n//g' file.jmx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/jp\@gc - JSON Path Extractor/JSON Extractor/g' file.jmx`

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible through any existing tool.

You'll have to either do manual replacement or through a custom parser of the XML test plan do the replacement.